# How to import a function from another directory file in python. Even have __init__.py file in that directory?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have directory structures like below..

```
   |---- folder1
        |---- __init__.py
        |---- python_file1.py
   |---- folder2
        |---- __init__.py
        |---- python_file2.py
```

while i try to import like this "folder2.python_file2 import some_function".

it give an error: **ImportError: cannot import name some_function**

and also i had look many answer in stack overflow they said to insert file path if the directory without `__init__.py` file. But even i have `__init__.py` I cant able to import function from that directory. Let me clear about this error.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the file from which you are importing?

Comment: I just importing the python function from the python_file2 in folder2 to python_file1 in folder1, And it is in Django Project.

Answer (score 2):

Python uses a period(.) operator to refer to the directories/modules starting from the current folder and moving upwards in the directory tree with each period.
For example, if you wish to import a file from python_file2.py and the file you are importing is contained in folder2 itself. This can be achieved by-
`from . import <filename>`
If you wish to import a file from python_file2.py and the file rests in folder1, you can add another period(.) to move one directory up and the statement will look like-
`from ..folder1 import <filename>`
`filename` is `python_file1.py` in your case. Hope this helps.